# 'rallyiterationcombobox' - How to select first or last iteration instead of the current iteration as the default value

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I am implementing a Rally app that allows the user to select a range of iterations to include for data sampling. I have a 'rallyiterationcombobox' instance to select the minimum and maximum for the iteration range. By default, the current iteration is selected from the list. Since I would like to include the largest range by default and then let the user narrow the search results if they wish, I would like it if the minimum iteration would default to the last on the list (first chronologically) and the maximum iteration would default to the first on the list (last chronologically).

It seems like I should be able to select an index for the 'value' attribute of the box in conjunction with the length of the list to select the last index, but that doesn't appear to be the case. The codes for the combo box is:

```
this.add({
    xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox',
    value: //should be able to set an index here
});
```